# Maximum acceleration of large peewee python queries

Tags: python, mysql, performance, peewee

I have a table in a database that has only 2 fields. I just need to send a certain number of new rows to it, regardless of their pk. The main problem is that queries even to the local database are much slower than the rest of the code. I would like to speed up this action as much as possible. I use python 3.10.10 and peewee ORM. Below is the code of the function that I call in several subprocesses. MySQL Database, MariaDB-10.8-Win10 (Open Server Panel).

```py
def insert_many_multi(self, data):
        with conn.atomic():
            if len(data)>998:
                for i in range(0, len(data), 998):
                        Binary.insert_many(data[i:i+998], fields=[Binary.id, Binary.value]).execute()
            else:
                Binary.insert_many(data, fields=[Binary.id, Binary.value]).execute()
```

List data is an array of tuples in the form [(None, 0), (None, 0), (None, 0), ... , (None, 0)]

Base and Binary model code

```py
conn = peewee.MySQLDatabase('Main', user='root', password='',
                         host='127.0.0.1', port=3306)
conn.close()

class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = conn


class Binary(BaseModel):
    id = peewee.AutoField(column_name='binary_id')
    value = peewee.IntegerField(column_name='value', null=True)
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'Binary'
```

I tried both doing massive transactions via .atomic() and doing them without them, the differences in speed are minimal.

Comment: how long does inserting one row take?  how long does inserting 999 rows take?

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.

Comment: I can’t say the exact time for sending one line. At the moment about 400 million lines are sent in 3.5 seconds. I need to get a time of about 0.3-1 seconds for an acceptable result.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; receiving the data. B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "tbl_name";  for analysis and try to answer ysth's and Rick James's requests.

Comment: what's a line?  if it's an inserted row, 400 million in 3.5 seconds sounds improbably fast, 1000+ times as fast as I would have guessed